# SOCI, pgsql function returning table record - type_conversion not working

Tags: c++, postgresql, soci

I have a pgsql function declared as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION auth.read_session(session_id varchar) RETURNS auth.sessions
```

It returns one record from the table auth.sessions.
I have a SOCI type_conversion that works perfectly fine when
I run `select * from auth.sessions where id = :id`.
It works when a matching record is found and when the result is NULL.
However, when I change the statement to:

```
select * from auth.read_session('invalid');
```

I get exception:

> Null value not allowed for this type while executing "select * from
>   auth.read_session('invalid')".

I tried with listing columns, passing soci::indicator, etc.
I cannot get it to work.
The exception comes from base type_conversion<>.

In type-conversion-traits.h there is a comment stating that:

> // default traits class type_conversion, acts as pass through for
>   row::get() // when no actual conversion is needed.

Why is no conversion needed? Yes my function returns the record of table type "auth.sessions".
Should it return RECORD instead so that the conversion gets launched?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only way this can be done is having the function return SETOF records. I believe the conversion is not needed as in my case the whole result was NULL and it cannot be somehow cast to my own type.
Returning a single record of table type works as long as there is any result.

It would work if a function was designed to always return a record, even if an empty one, but still a "record".

Answer (score 0):

PadThink you're right about the return. To call this function the way you're doing you need to return a QUERY, TABLE, or SETOF records.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: Yes, the doc says:
"If the last query happens to return no rows at all, the null value will be returned". I wasn't sure about it at the time as in psql the same query somehow shows me "an empty row" instead of just simply NULL. I wonder how it's done, as unsetting echo_hidden does not reveal any magic involved. But psql seems to follow declared return type and yields en empty tuple instead of NULL.